# Double line spacing in references list in R Markdown using xelatex

Tags: r-markdown, xelatex, biblatex

How do I increase the line spacing of my bibliography/references section. My output is as .pdf, and I am using a .csl of harvard. I have a references.bib. All of this works fine but the only thing I need to do is double the line spacing of the references

I have tried the following and have put the lines a) and b) in various places. If they are anywhere other than where they are below the file won't knit to .pdf, and where the 2 lines are currently, it does knit to .pdf but they have no effect.

```
---
title: "My Title"

geometry: "left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm"

output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: yes
#    toc: yes

header-includes:
# Use the packages
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \usepackage{placeins}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
a)  - \usepackage{biblatex}
b) - \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}

# Set the font
  - \setmainfont{Calibri}

# Header and Footer Settings
  - \fancyhf{}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}

# References and bibliography settings
csl: */UoL_Harvard.csl

bibliography: references.bib

---
\fancyhf{}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{********}
\fancyhead[L]{GEOG3050}
\rfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after days of searching for the answer, I have finally come across the following
I hope this helps someone

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57637/hanging-indents-in-bibliography